# How to make Navigation Based application using iOS SDK 5.0 in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: xcode

How to create navigation based applications in new Xcode 4.2 having sdk 5.0? When I used IOS SDK 4.3 I used to get navigation based application while creating projects from Xcode. Now it seems Apple removed the option for navigation based applications from new version.

Comment: It is strange that they have removed the option to generate a navigation based application.

Answer (score 1):

there is no any viewController class with a new navigation based project in 4.2(latest).Navigationbased app known as Pagebased application in 4.2. so you need to add manually view controller subclasses. Thanks